# Cannot run exported application

Tags: xcode, macos

I've developed a simple MacOS application (i.e. a product consisting of main application and launch helper application) with Xcode 9.4. Application runs fine in Xcode. I've archived and exported the app (either "Export without re-signing" or "Development" using "Automatic signing"). The export process runs without errors.

However, it is not possible to the application. Upon starting outside of Xcode, *nothing* happens; no error message etc.

How can this be further diagnosed?

Comment: You should run the app from Terminal by a command like `MyApplication.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApplication`. This should show you console outputs.

Comment: Great- found the error thanks to your advice. Fixing that will be another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it thanks to @clemens. Embedded libraries have their place inside the generated package in `/Contents/Frameworks`. Since I had previously embedded a login item I had set a `/Contents/Library/LoginItems` target path that was used *below* Frameworks which is clearly not the expected place. Removing the library, cleaning the path and re-adding fixed it for me.